# How to select git revision range from an empty repository to HEAD?

Tags: git

I want select the revision range between the empty repository and HEAD.

(I do realize this is, in effect, the same thing as just looking at the files at HEAD! However, the reason is because I'm feeding it into an external tool that only accepts a revision range).

I think it would be something like...

```
0..HEAD
```

...but I can't find any example or documentation of this.

Comment: What do you mean by «select» ? Do you want to output every commit since the beginning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Well, not directly anyway.  The set of all commits reachable from `HEAD` is simply: *`HEAD`, selected as a revision range* (as opposed to *`HEAD`, selected as a single commit*).  But:

> ... the reason is because I'm feeding it into an external tool that only accepts a revision range ...

This is where we have a problem, with a rather hacky solution.  We can illustrate it with `git cherry-pick` because `git cherry-pick` behaves differently depending on whether we name a single commit:

```
git cherry-pick a123456
```

or a range:

```
git cherry-pick cafedad..a123456
```

for instance.  The former picks (copies) just the one commit `a123456`, while the latter copies all commits *reachable from* `a123456`, excluding any commits reachable from `cafedad`.

(This does not make `cherry-pick` itself bad, because it's not very sensible to cherry-pick starting from the root commit.  However, it *does* make sense to use `git rebase` starting from the root, which is why `git rebase -i` now has a `--root` flag.  The problem is slightly different, but closely related.)

That is, suppose we have the following chain of commits:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master
             \
              G--H   <-- branch
```

with the actual hash ID of commit `E` being `cafedad` and the actual hash ID of commit `H` being `a123456`.  If we want to copy the two `branch` commits atop `F`, we can `git checkout -b new master` to get this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master, new (HEAD)
             \
              G--H   <-- branch
```

and then run the `cherry-pick` with the range syntax to get this:

```
                 G'-H'  <-- new (HEAD)
                /
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master
             \
              G--H   <-- branch
```

where `G'` and `H'` are the copies of the two interesting commits.

But what if, for some reason—this is where `git cherry-pick` is *not* a good example—we want to copy commits `A` through `F` inclusive?  We cannot `git cherry-pick ..master`, nor even `git cherry-pick badf00d..master` if commit `A` has hash ID `badf00d`.  The former just copies `F`, while the latter copies `B-C-D-E-F`, omitting `A`.

The solution is to create a disconnected commit, so that we can force a range *syntax* while excluding *nothing*.  That is, if we have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master
             \
              G--H   <-- branch
```

we can create a new commit `I` that is in a completely separate graph:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master
             \
              G--H   <-- branch

I   <-- independent
```

Now we can write `independent..master`, which means *all commits working backwards from `F` but excluding all commits working backwards from `I`*.  Starting at `I` and working backwards, we list commit `I`: so we'll toss `I` from our `F`-on-back set.  That leaves us with commits `A-B-C-D-E-F` selected, just as we want.

So:

```
git checkout --orphan independent
git commit -m 'pointless commit made to satisfy external tool'
```

after which we can run `git checkout` to update `HEAD` and then use:

```
external-tool independent..HEAD
```

which the tool will see as a range and do a revision-range selection that includes all commits reachable from `HEAD`, while tossing the not-selected-anyway independent ("orphan") branch's commits.

Comment: To avoid the HEAD churn and any checkout hooks, ```git update-ref refs/independent $(git commit-tree -m - `git mktree <&-`)```

Answer (score 1):

The first commit of a repository can be get with `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`, so to do something like `0..HEAD` you can do `git log $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)..HEAD`

Note: by default, the first commit will not be returned. If you want to include the first commit, you can add `git --boundary log $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)..HEAD`